# How can I get the current column value of a table

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I am trying to  find the value of a column in the current row  from the  table . But it is not working. Here is the code

```js
<script>
    $('#tblEntry').keyup(function (e) {
    var monHrs= $(this).closest('tr').find("#MondayNetHrs").val();
  var monHrs= $(this).closest('tr').find("#TuesdayNetHrs").val();
}   
</script>
```

```html
<table id="tblEntry" class="table table-striped">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control date-input" })</td>
                                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToDate, new { @class = "form-control date-input" })</td>
                                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SundayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MondayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TuesdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.WednesdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ThursdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FridayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SaturdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NetHrsPerWeek, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HolidayEnt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control  w-100", @readonly = "readonly" } })</td>
                                        <td><a href="" title="Delete Rows">Delete</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: My solution doesn't work for you? Or any further issue on it ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

add id to all your inputs

```
  <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SundayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @id="sundayNetHrs" @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
```

and jquery

```
 var sunHrs= $("#sundayNetHrs").val();
```

or in your case

```
 $('#tblEntry').keyup(function (e) {
    var id = this.attr("id");
      var value = this.val();
}
```

Comment: It will not work for the table having  multiple rows dynamically adding

Comment: @AlanPauil just try it and let me know if you still have some problems

Answer (score 0):

You can add the item name into class and use class selector to get that item.

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.TestModel>
<table id="tblEntry" class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>FromDate
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.FromDate, new {  @class = "FromDate form-control date-input" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.ToDate, new {  @class = "ToDate form-control date-input" })</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => item.SundayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "SundayNetHrs form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => item.MondayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "MondayNetHrs form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => item.TuesdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "TuesdayNetHrs form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => item.WednesdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "WednesdayNetHrs form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => item.ThursdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "ThursdayNetHrs form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => item.FridayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "FridayNetHrs form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => item.SaturdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "SaturdayNetHrs form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => item.NetHrsPerWeek, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "NetHrsPerWeek form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => item.HolidayEnt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "HolidayEnt form-control  w-100", @readonly = "readonly" } })</td>
                <td><a href="" title="Delete Rows">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $('#tblEntry').keyup(function (e) {
        console.info(e.target);
        console.info($(e.target).parent().parent().find(".MondayNetHrs").val());
    });
</script>
```

[image]